# AWS S3 object level ACL for groups which are predefined

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

Can we define object level ACL having group in which I can club users from other AWS account. Idea is having a group to which I can add or remove users. I know ACL are maintained at object level and for every new grantee I have to add it in ACL. But having a group assigned to ACL and then modifying that group will be way easier approach. I know it supports predefined groups like authenticated user . Is there a way to create other predefined groups based on application need?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use ACLs, they're a legacy access control mechanism and they're going to bite you.

According to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/acl-overview.html) (emphasis mine):

> Access control lists (ACLs) are one of the resource-based access
> policy options (see Overview of managing access) that you can use to
> manage access to your buckets and objects. You can use ACLs to grant
> basic read/write permissions to other AWS accounts. **There are limits**
> **to managing permissions using ACLs.**
>
> **For example, you can grant permissions only to other AWS accounts; you**
> **cannot grant permissions to users in your account. You cannot grant**
> **conditional permissions, nor can you explicitly deny permissions.** ACLs
> are suitable for specific scenarios. For example, if a bucket owner
> allows other AWS accounts to upload objects, permissions to these
> objects can only be managed using object ACL by the AWS account that
> owns the object.

As you can see from the limitations, it doesn't seem suitable for your use case.

There is a better solution for resource-based access policies and it's called [bucket policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-iam-policies.html). They allow you to grant access to prefixes in the bucket based on IAM principals such as users and roles or AWS services, even from other AWS accounts. (note, that IAM groups don't work).

I suggest you review the [Access Policy Guidelines](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/access-policy-alternatives-guidelines.html) before making your decision.